# what's exactly the string of "^A" is?

Tags: c++, character, ascii

I run my code on an online judgement. I log the string, key. Below is my code:

```
fprintf(stderr, "key=%s, and key.size()=%d\n", key.c_str(), key.size());
```

But the result is this:

```
key=^A, and key.size()=8
```

I want to what is the `^A` represent in ascii. `^A`'s size is 2 rather than 8, but it shows that it is 8. I view the result by vim, and the log_file is encoded by UTF-8. Why?

Comment: What value the c_str() is returning actually ? Share the structure Key, and the values you are storing to it's data members.

Comment: What is `key` ?

Comment: @Mazhar c_str() return const char *.

Comment: Can you please share your code ? There could be something wrong with the functions that you wrote. Share the c_str(), size() and the key structure.

Comment: @tkausl  key is a std::string, the data is provided by OJ.

Comment: @Mazhar key is a std::string. I don't define it myself.

Comment: We won't be able to help you unless we could see the values you are setting. You can share a dummy code containing the values you're setting in your original code. I don't think people will be able to help with that little knowledge about your code.

Comment: Are you viewing the result on the console or in a file.  If it is in a file, which editor are you using.  ^A could mean binary 1.

Comment: @cup I view it in a log_file, and the encode of the file is UTF-8, which is showed by ":set fileencoding".. And I use vim to open it.

Comment: @Mazhar I view the log by vim, and the log_file encoding is UTF-8,  the real code is below, and I simply it as what I asked at first.   ```RetCode Store::Append(const string & key, const string &value) {
        if (write_log_index < 100 && (write_log_index%1 == 0)) {
            write_log_index++;
            fprintf(stderr, "write info:key:%s, value:%s, and size=%d,%d \n", key.c_str(), value.c_str(),key.size(), value.size());
        }


        ```

Comment: @Mazhar `c_str()` is C++. I've retagged the question. To the OP: Please use relevant tags only

Comment: You could output int(c) for each character c of the string

Comment: @Mazhar  I have solve it by myself. Happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your viewer is electing to show you the bytes interpreted using a character encoding of its choosing and electing to show the resulting characters in [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation).

Other viewers could make different choices on both counts or allow you to indicate what you want. For example, [control picture characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_Pictures) (␁) instead of caret notation.

For a `std:string` `c_str()` is terminated by an additional `\x00` byte following the actual value. You often use `c_str()` with functions that expect a string to be `\x00` terminated. This applies to `fprintf`. In such cases, what's read ends just before the first `\x00` seen.

You have several `\x00` bytes in your string, which, of course, contributes to `size()` but `fprintf` will stop right at the first one (and not count it).

Comment: Thank you. I know the reason behind the phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve it by myself. If you write a std::string "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00end" to a file and open it with vim later, you will get '^A'.

This is my test code:

```
string sss("\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00end");
ofstream of("of.txt");
for (int i=0; i<sss.size(); i++) {
    of.put(sss[i]);
}

of.close();
```

After I open the file "of.txt", I saw "^A";